# How to use iframe in Power BI

Tags: html, powerbi

I am trying to embed a web page in our report, here we have a table in our report we want to use `iframe` in rows of the table to open link in report it self to show the the content of the web page, is this possible to do this could some one suggest any idea for this ?

Any other way would also do rather than `iframe`

I would not want to use any 3rd party tools.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://whatthefact.bi/power-bi/data-visualization/display-website-within-power-bi-dynamically/ ?

Comment: Or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUfAhX9h_VA&t=409s ?

Comment: We dont want to use any 3rd party tools